# Multimedia volume instead of Phone volume in Android

Tags: android, volume

I'm making a simple music application for android.
It's working fine, but when I want to change the multimedia volume I can't make it directly from the application. 
If I click the volume up/down button it changes the Phone calls volume, so I should go to another application (game) and when clicking again on those buttons it changes Multimedia volume.

Do you know any way to select that those volume buttons works just for multimedia volume in my application instead of whole phone?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if there is a default method for this, but you could always do this:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
{ 
   if (   keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN || 
          keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) { 
       //magic goes here
   } else {
       return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event); 
   }
}
```

Comment: On most phones I have tested, they volume value is not properly updated until `onKeyUp`... you should handle that method instead

Answer (score 2):

What is really the easiset is this

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setVolumeControlStream%28int%29

just call setVolumeControlStream from your activity's onCreate and pass STREAM_MUSIC or whatever you are running your audio on

Answer (score 1):

The built-in class you are looking for is `AudioManager`.  I believe the particular method you need is `setStreamVolume`.  The stream type is going to be `AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC` You can read about it [here][1].

Edit:  I guess I can't make this a hyperlink....so [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html) is the link to the top level class...strange.

[1]: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setStreamVolume(int, int, int)